# Foxit Reader | Unable to find snapshot tool

Tags: snapshot, foxitreader

I just discovered that the awesome Foxit Reader is available for Ubuntu :D.

I also discovered that the very handy snapshot tool is NOT in the Ubuntu version :(. ALthough the manual refers to the tool tab.

I'm installing the software from the FoxitReader.enu.setup.x64.1.0.1.0925(r189237).run file, which is included in the packed FoxitReader1.01.0925_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar.gz file.

Am I missing something (a little box to tick) or is the tool gone missing..?

Thanks TCW

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are actually looking for something that you can find in Foxit reader for Windows OS.

However, Foxit Reader available for Ubuntu(which is a Linux based operating system) seems quite different in terms of both features and UIUX design. I would say probably you didn't miss doing anything but the too just wasn't there. Fortunately there is a user manual of Foxit Reader for linux proving my point. I could not find this tool being mentioned in this manual.
http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/reader/en_us/FoxitReader1.0_QuickGuideforLinux.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a snapshot tool in Foxit Reader. If you're using Gnome taste in Linux, you can use the snapshot tool in your distro, or just download it from your friendly repository.
It works great and you can either save as a .png file or copy in your clipboard to paste in your application that you're using.
It's perfect, simplest and faster as Linux.